# Authorization from app

Tags: java, instagram-api

I write a lite instagram client (Instagram is a part of client).
And I need to the user can authorizate in Instagram without web-form (to I don't need to send the user in his web-browser).
At this moment I use a link `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`.
It sends the user to the web-form where he can input his login and password.
How I can send his login and password programatically without using of the web-brower?

Answer (score -1):

No way to login without the Instagram's web interface. Use a Webview to open the auth URL and redirect back to app.

Comment: Why? Web-browser  is all same program only native.

Comment: Why for what? Using webview will make the process look like its all within the app.

Comment: Yeah, just it brokes all design and contains a small elements and the user will need to scale page to perform a click.